# How to show half of the middle section when scrolled to the top and bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position

I've written this code for a simple html page in which there are three sections. The top(first) and bottom(third) are full screen sections and the middle section has to be shown with both the top and bottom sections i.e., the upper half of the middle section with the top section and the bottom half with the third section.

I was able to show the first part correctly(when scroll position is at the top) but not the second part(which is when scroll position at the bottom).

Can anybody tell me how can I achieve that?

Full page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeQG9.png

When scroll position is at the top: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJQKd.png

When scroll position is at the bottom: https://i.stack.imgur.com/weRci.png

```css
* {
     font-family: monospace;
 }
 h2 {
     font-size: 100px;
     font-family: monospace;
 }
 
 .section-1, .section-3 {
     height: 100vh;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
 }
 .section-2 h6 {
     font-size: 18px;
     position: relative;
     margin: 80px 0 !important;
 }
 .section-2 p {
     font-size: 20px;
     position: relative;
 }
 .section-2 {
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: -145px;
 }
 .section-2 h6:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     height: 60px;
     width: 1px;
     background: #000;
     left: 50%;
     top: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
 <h2>SECTION 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="section-2">
 <h6>Scroll</h6>
 <p>Studio Liana Lalush</p>
</div>
<div class="section-3">
 <h2>SECTION 3</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting like this:

**Note: check out my answer in full screen mode**

**Demo:**

```css
* {
  font-family: monospace;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.section-1,
.section-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section-2 h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 70px 0 !important;
}

.section-2 p {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.section-2 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 98%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.section-2 h6:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  left: 50%;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
  <h2>SECTION 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="section-2">
  <h6>Scroll</h6>
  <p>Studio Liana Lalush</p>
</div>
<div class="section-3">
  <h2>SECTION 3</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me with this. I just tried this on my desktop and laptop but it doesn't work. It shows the entire second section in the first section.

Comment: Take screenshort and share it @Rahul

Comment: You can check it on the responsive mode or lambda test but here is a ss from me: https://i.imgur.com/APEfvwp.png

Comment: Are you checking this on a laptop? It is working there but not on a wide screen. My screen is 2560px wide.

Comment: There must be some solution without having to write multiple media queries. I wish someone with more experience than us could help.

Comment: Really appreciate all the effort you've put it to solve the issue though.

Comment: please share current ouput pic, I will try to fix @Rahul

Comment: Lets move this discussion to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198946/discussion-between-rahul-and-amaresh-s-m

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. You only need to change in css code.

```
* {
    font-family: monospace;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.section-1 {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.section-3{
    height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.section-2 h6 {
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 80px 0 !important;
}
.section-2 p {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.section-2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -145px;
}
.section-2 h6:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 1px;
    background: #000;
    left: 50%;
    top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me with this. It sort of worked on my laptop but when I viewed it on a larger screen the second section is a little off. I think it could be fixed by adding multiple media queries but this is not what I was hoping for. There must be some good solution to this.